# Interstitial Ad Loading After every 1 Minte

Tags: android, loops, admob, ads, interstitial

I want to Display a Interstitial Ad after every one minute...
can any one please explain with sample code ...

thanks
Please

```
    interstitialAds = new InterstitialAd(this, "Your_Pub_ID");
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    interstitialAds.loadAd(adRequest);
    interstitialAds.setAdListener(this);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous way to display Interstitial ads at regular interval of time. You can add codes in your app in order to display Interstitial ads at regular interval of time.

---

prepareAd();

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Log.i("hello", "world");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    } else {
                       Log.d("TAG"," Interstitial not loaded");
                    }

                    prepareAd();


                }
            });

        }
    }, 20, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

---

However, I (you can say that admob) strongly stopping you to doing such stuffs. It is against AdMob policy and your account will get suspended if you do so.

If you want to learn more stuffs about android app development and how to place admob ad in your application. I recommend you to visit this website.

http://www.elegantespace.com/how-to-load-interstitial-ad-at-regular-interval-of-time/

Answer (score 8):

Firstly this will be a **VERY** bad experience for your users. I would strongly recommend against it.

But if you really want to piss your users off then something like:

```
final Runnable runanble = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      wait(60000);
      runOnUiThread(intersitial.showAd());
      interstitial.loadAd(new request());
    }
  }
};
```

Edit:
**DO NOT DO THIS**. I have had word back from Admob that this directly contravenes their policies and it will get your account disabled.

Comment: If I want to display Interstitial Ad every five minutes, should I still loadAd right after showing one? Or should I load the ad only one minute before showing the ad? Does it affect performance ?

Comment: You can load an ad any time before showing (you just need to allow enough time for it to load over a typically crappy connection). I load mine at the start of a game and show it at the end. But as I added above DO NOT auto show interstitials every X mins as Admob consider this a policy violation.

Comment: @William not working, I am getting unable to resolve showAd()

Answer (score 7):

This is against admob policies and they will ban you also this will be very bad experience for user.

**EDIT:** link to policy (refer "`Repeated or recurring interstitials`" section) - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but should be a comment!

Comment: the answer is very simple. create a thread that will call your ad to load and if laoded then display keep it waiting for 6000 ms.

Comment: Please share the URL of the policy that is stating this.

Comment: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287

here is the URL @ShajeelAfzal . Please check "Repeated or recurring interstitials" section

Answer (score 1):

```
place it in oncreate method

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 420000);
```

after oncreate method

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//Your code to show add
// Create the interstitial.
// Prepare the Interstitial Ad
Interstitial = new InterstitialAd(your activity);
// Insert the Ad Unit ID
interstitial.setAdUnitId("your id ");

//Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);

// Request for Ads
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

// Add a test device to show Test Ads
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.addTestDevice("")
.build();

 // Load ads into Banner Ads
 adView.loadAd(adRequest);

 // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
 Interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

 // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
 interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
 public void onAdLoaded() {
 // Call displayInterstitial() function
 displayInterstitial();
 }
 });
 handler.postDelayed(this, 600000); // 1000 - Milliseconds
 }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
public void onAdLoaded() {
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            MainActivity.this.interstitialAd.show();
        } 
    }, 5000);
} });
```

Answer (score 1):

just simple. create Timertask and schedule every 60000 ms. but it is bad UX for users. don't do it

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 60000);
```